# ruby/rails equivalent to javascript decodeURIComponent?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, character-encoding

I have some content (html) that is being encoded as a result of this javascript (from [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.btoa)) and sent to my rails application:

```
function encode_utf8_b64(string) {
return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(string)));
}
```

The correspond js code to get it back to original is this:

```
function decode_utf8_b64(string) {
return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(string)));
}
```

My question is, is there an equivalent in ruby of decodeURIComponent()?  So far I have this that gets it part of the way out, but I'm missing the last step of decodeURIComponent:

```
CGI::escape(Base64.decode64(string))
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[URI.unescape](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI/Escape.html#M009397) could probably help:

```
def decode_utf8_b64(string)
  URI.unescape(CGI::escape(Base64.decode64(string)))
end
```

you have to add the necessary rubygem too:

```
require 'uri'
```

I've tested this on ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: thanks - when I apply URI.unescape or URI.decode, I get an "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8" error.  It seems that the output of the CGI::escape() is US-ASCII.  When I tried to use Iconv to convert the string to UTF-8 before applying URI.unescape, it stopped throwing the error but seemed to just remove one of the deencoding steps so the output was still a mess.  Any tips?  Or maybe this is a separate issue.