# Encodeuricomponent decoding it in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, url, encoding

Normally rails magically decodes all `params`. Now I got a javascript which does `params="value="+encodeURIComponent('ab#cd');` and then calls `http://server/controller?value=ab%23cd`. If I access `params[:value]` in my controller, it contains `ab%23cd` and not `ab#cd` as I would expect.

How to solve this? Why does rails no auto decoding of this param?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ruby/rails equivalent to javascript decodeURIComponent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457925/ruby-rails-equivalent-to-javascript-decodeuricomponent)

Comment: No duplicate as my question is related on the auto decoding of params, not an external method to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5):

Rails "automagically" handles parameters with the following logic.

If the request is GET it will decode anything in the query string:

```
GET http://server/controller?value=ab%23cd
  On the server this will generate params['value'] as ab#cd
```

If the request is a POST with a query string it will not decode it:

```
POST http://server/controller?value=ab%23cd
  On the server this will generate params['value'] as ab%23cd
```

If the request is a POST with data parameters, it will decode it:

```
POST http://server/controller
  data: value=ab%23cd
  On the server this will generate params['value'] as ab#cd
```

I suspect that you're seeing this issue because you're including a query string with a `POST` request instead of a `GET` request and so Rails isn't decoding the query string.