# Rails encoded url query plus sign not properly decoded

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Raw Email is

```
abc+2@gmail.com
```

For the haml file, I have javascripts like this

```
$('#Search_email').on('click', function(e){
   var val = encodeURIComponent($('#search_email').val());
   window.location.search = 'email='+val;
});
```

In the query url, it shows correctly as

```
url?email=abc%2B2%40gmail.com
```

However, for the controller, when I use the debugger to monitor, it shows only

```
params[:email] = "abc 2@gmail.com"
```

Does anyone know what happens, why rails decodes directly and in a wrong way. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you observing the query URL?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038841/encodeuricomponent-decoding-it-in-rails  .  Perhaps this will explain what you're seeing.

Comment: answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464885/rails-plus-sign-in-get-request-replaced-by-space